# Is it possible to add an onclick listener to a QCheckBox?

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt

I have a bunch of dynamically created checkboxes and the last checkbox is labelled: 'check all/ uncheck all'.

Is it possible to have an onclick listener attached to the very last checkbox? Or will I have to resort to using a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to listen just for click events, since the state of a `QCheckBox` can also be triggered by the keyboard. In most cases you'd want to listen to the [stateChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox.html#stateChanged) signal.

Comment: I resorted to a simple button in the end, but I didn't know this so thank you